# Where do I report a UI issue that I do not like?

Tags: 13.10, software-center, gui, design

I have just installed ubuntu, I am picky about UI design choices and have spotted something I do not like, but this time instead of just hating it I wish I could tell the ubuntu team so maybe just maybe someone in a future release might take 5 minutes to change it...

Where do I report such an issue?

The issue in question is :

[image]

[image]

I think the little arrow down and the labels next to it are too close to the edge. The arrow should be padded at least 5px and the label should be further from the arrow. When a whole list of such items shows up it looks real naff.

Comment: The design mailing list on that question is the right place to go.